# Installing via composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an extremely simple question - When installing a program via composer (when not part of an existing framework like Laravel), how do I know what to put in the autoload section?

Here's what I've got...

```
{
    "name": "Search",
    "description": "Get search results from Solr",
    "keywords": [
        "search",
        "solr"
    ],
    "require": {
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "solarium/solarium": "3.2.*",
        "twig/twig" : "~1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use composer you get an PSR-4 autoloader. So when you use install your packages you can include the autoloader.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Here is the introduction. There is an autoload section and some good examples.